# How do I cut a hole in a vector object I've drawn with the pen tool in Paint Shop Pro 8?

Tags: vector, corel-paint-shop-pro, pen-tool

On a whim, I decided to try to recreate a high resolution Paint Shop Pro 8 logo icon.

The icon is a red painter's palette with a paint prush and the text "PSP 8".

I traced the outline of the palette, traced the paint brush handle, bristle clamp, and bristles, and typed the text all on different layers.

*My difficulty comes in that the palette has a hole cut in the middle of it for the artist's thumb to grip.
I've traced a vector path for the hole, but I don't know how to make the center of the hole (which I've specified should have no fill) be empty space in the middle of the outer outline of the palette.*

I'm sure that this will be better illustrated by images than by my words, so here you are:

[image: Original icon pixels vs. Work in Progress]

Now, it would be the easiest thing in the world to convert the palette and the hole to raster layers, select the outline of the hole, highlight the palette layer and delete those pixels, but I want to get better at using vector drawing tools and being able to cut a hole out of the interior seems like a pretty basic skill to have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a hollow shape, reverse the contour of the "cutout" shape.

From the [PSP 9 User Guide](http://www.corel.com/6763/psp_downloads/pub/en/psp900enug.pdf):

### To reverse a path or contour:

1. From the `Tools` toolbar, select the Pen tool [image: Pen Tool].
2. From the `Tool Options` palette’s Mode section, click `Edit` [image: Edit].
3. Click on a contour or path, and then select one node on the contour.
4. Right-click on the path or contour, choose `Edit` from the context menu, and choose:
   `Reverse Path` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + R</kbd>) or `Reverse Contour` (<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>). Note: You can also access these commands by choosing `Objects > Edit`.

[image: Hollow Shape]